# How to install package via yum in Fedora

Tags: linux, command-line

How do I install software using `yum`?

Can you tell me another way to install package in Fedora?

Comment: Fedora 15 isn't supported any more.  If you can, I'd suggest you use Fedora 19 or 20 as you'll get far more support for them in the Fedora forums and if you have to report bugs.

Comment: Please note that Fedora 15 reached end-of-life over two years ago, in June 2012. That means that security and bug fix updates are no longer produced. Please update to a current release. (Right now, F20 is your best bet!) Also, Fedora 15 was kind of a rough release, with early systemd and big changes to the desktop environments. Newer releases are a lot more polished.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sudo yum install foo` will look for `foo` in the package repositories and install it if it exists. Sometimes the name of packages is not obvious, so you may want to use `yum search foo` to see if there are any packages available pertaining to "foo". `man yum` will give you some details about the packaging program.